# Nlog log to another directory

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, nlog

By default Nlog logs to default application folder

```
        <target xsi:type="File" name="f" 
      fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
             layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} 
   ${exception:message=tostring}" />
```

Currently my application is in C directory and I want Nlog to log to D directory in specific folder. I read about

```
            fileName="${tempdir:folder=myapptmp}/sample.log"
```

and

```
       ${specialfolder:dir=String:file=String:folder=Enum}
```

Special folder it seems logs into MyDocuments, Pictures. So not much useful. Tempdir I am not sure about. Has anybody done this earlier or has any idea about it

My Nlog config

```
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <!-- 
     See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file 
        for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
        -->
      <targets>
     <!-- add your targets here -->


       <target name="File" xsi:type="File"  
     fileName="D:\Sushil\DwebLogging\log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${exception: 
     format=tostring}" />
        <rules>
         <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />
      </rules>
      </nlog>
```

Comment: There's no closing `</targets>` tag in the sample above. Copy/paste issue or accurate?

Comment: Ah.. That was the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just specify the full path in the `fileName` attribute like so;

```
<target name="File" xsi:type="File"  fileName="D:\Logging\SomeFile-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
```

A full working sample is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <target name="File" xsi:type="File"  fileName="D:\Logging\Sample-${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.csv">
      <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
        <column name="Index" layout="${counter}" />
        <column name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" />
        <column name="Time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <column name="Severity" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
        <column name="Location" layout="${callsite:className=False:fileName=True:includeSourcePath=False:methodName=False}" />
        <column name="Detail" layout="${message}" />
        <column name="Exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

If you're still not seeing your file, then it's possible that the process the application is running under doesn't have write access to the file (NLog will fail silently by default). This is most commonly found if you're app is a web app in IIS as the IIS process will need write access to the folder which it will not have by default.

Comment: I tried as below but it is not working                                                  
        <target name="File" xsi:type="File"  
           fileName="D:\Sushil\DwebLogging\log-${date:format=yyyy-MM-
          dd}.log"
          layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} 
          ${exception: format=tostring}" />
 <rules>
           <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="File" />
           </rules>

Comment: What's your full NLog.config? Are the targets set up and matching the `<target name="File">`?

Comment: Updated question with Nlog.config

Comment: Updated answer with working config and potential gotcha on IIS

Answer (score 1):

I also looked into this and I figured it out from a relative path since I don't always know the full path when it's deployed to a server for example Azure or something.

My config file is in the root of the project to detect it.

In the NLog.config you need to a dot to the target to make it relative.

Not working version:

```
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="/App_Data/Logs/file.txt" />
```

Working version:

```
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="./App_Data/Logs/file.txt" />
```

How my rules look like:

```
 <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
```